# How to send email attachment using mailx -a with a different attachment name?

Tags: mailx

We could do this using `uuencode`:

```
uuencode actual_file display_file_name | mailx testemail@org.com
```

Could you please advice how this can be done using `mailx -a`?

The only option seems to be to copy file with a different name, and then try.

Comment: Symlinks come to mind

Comment: Hello Jeff, Apologies.. I didn't quite get your suggestion.

Comment: Looks like John picked up on it in their answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `-a` option, the `mailx` program will do all the necessary conversions to base64 and then to MIME format for you. No need to use `uuencode`

```
echo | mailx -a actual_file testemail@org.com
```

The only trick is that for some reason `mailx` does not work if you put `-a actual_file` after the recipient email address.

Note that using `echo` command makes sure that `mailx` will not ask you to enter subject and message body manually.

p.s. replying to your comment... AFAIK, there is no such option in `mailx` program to provide different display name. In order to attach a file such that it is shown under a different name in e-mail, you can do

```
ln -s actual_file attached_file
echo | mailx -a attached_file testemail@org.com
rm -f attached_file
```

Comment: Hello John, Firstly, Thanks for your reply. My question was, how do we show a different file name on the email? Eg: If I am attaching 1234.log onto the email, I would typically like to show it with a different name, say : testing_details.log . This can be done using uuencode, but couldn't find any way to do this using mailx -a

Comment: ah... now got what you want. added the code to my reply.

Comment: on this site "thanks" are expressed by marking the answer as "accepted" if you are satisfied with it :)

Comment: Instead of -a use -A to add attachment.